# How to overload generic function in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance

I have this code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program {
    static void Visit(Visitor visitor) {
        var animal = new List<Animal>();
        var cat = new List<Cat>();
        
        visitor.Visit(animal);
        visitor.Visit(cat);
    }
    
    public static void Main() {
        Visit(new Visitor());
        Visit(new FirstVisitor());
        Visit(new SecondVisitor());
        Visit(new ThirdVisitor());
    }
    
    public class Visitor {
        public virtual void Visit<T>(List<T> objects) where  T : Animal {
            Console.WriteLine("Called visit from base visitor");
        }
    }
    
    public class FirstVisitor : Visitor {
        public void Visit(List<Cat> cats) {
            Console.WriteLine("called cats from first visitor");        
        }
    }
    
    public class SecondVisitor : Visitor {
        public void Visit(List<Animal> cats) {
            Console.WriteLine("called animal from second visitor");     
        }
    }
    
    public class ThirdVisitor : Visitor {
        public override void Visit<T>(List<T> objs) {
            Console.WriteLine("called obj from third visitor");     
        }
    }
    
    
    public class Animal {
        
    }
    
    public class Cat : Animal {
        
    }
}
```

and the output is

```
Called visit from base visitor
Called visit from base visitor
Called visit from base visitor
Called visit from base visitor
Called visit from base visitor
Called visit from base visitor
called obj from third visitor
called obj from third visitor
```

How to properly overload base class Visitor so methods in derived classes First and Second visitor will be called?

I have similar code in C++ which works fine.
There are many Visitors and descendants of Animal class.

I would like to be able to override base method Visit for visiting all Animal classes at once or override method just for specific Animal.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: (C#) Generics aren't (C++) templates, despite some superficial resemblances between the two. There's no specialization in generics.

Comment: Generics are not templates. Your `Visit` methods are _not_ overrides of the base classes method, and that's the only one you ever call. And because of how variance works, they can't, it would violate type safety.

Comment: It's not possible to do this. If it was, you could just assign a `FirstVisitor` reference to a `Visitor` reference and then call its `Visit()` method with a list of any type that implements `Animal`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a solution on another forum; just posting it there to help someone else with similar problem.

```
    static void Visit(Visitor visitor) {
        var animal = new List<Animal>();
        var cat = new List<Cat>();
        
        dynamic vis = visitor;
        vis.Visit(animal);
        vis.Visit(cat);
    }
```

When the variable is converted to dynamic before calling Visit it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

is this output you want ?

```
----------Visitor-----------  
Called visit from base visitor  
Called visit from base visitor  
----------end-----------

----------FirstVisitor-----------  
Called visit from base visitor  
called cats from first visitor  
Called visit from base visitor  
called cats from first visitor  
----------end-----------

----------SecondVisitor-----------  
Called visit from base visitor  
called animal from second visitor  
Called visit from base visitor  
called animal from second visitor  
----------end-----------

----------ThirdVisitor-----------  
Called visit from base visitor  
called obj from third visitor    
Called visit from base visitor    
called obj from third visitor  
----------end-----------
```

If this is you want result, you should override your method of superclass in subclass and use method of superclass to print "Called visit from base visitor".
use "base" (special word) to call your method of superclass.

These code I modified from your code.

```
public class FirstVisitor : Visitor {
    public override void Visit<T>(List<T> objects){
        base.Visit(objects);
        Console.WriteLine("called cats from first visitor");        
    }
}

public class SecondVisitor : Visitor {
    public override void Visit<T>(List<T> objects){
        base.Visit(objects);
        Console.WriteLine("called animal from second visitor");     
    }
}

public class ThirdVisitor : Visitor {
    public override void Visit<T>(List<T> objects){
        base.Visit(objects);
        Console.WriteLine("called obj from third visitor");     
    }
}
```

Hope it helps